# Index against a subset of rows?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, index

Is it possible to create an index against a subset of rows fulfilling a certain condition?

If it is possible how does one ensure the index is used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, what you're talking about is a [Filtered Index](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280372%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).  It works just like you think, by creating an index off of a subset of data.  Below is an excerpt from the above reference:

> A filtered index is an optimized nonclustered index, especially **suited to cover queries that select from a well-defined subset of data**. It uses a **filter predicate** to **index a portion of rows** in the table. *A well-designed filtered index can improve query performance, reduce index maintenance costs, and reduce index storage costs compared with full-table indexes.*

To your other question:

> how does one ensure the index is used?

A few things will dictate this index being used:

1. A well-designed filtered index correlated with
2. A well-designed query

Obviously things like data distribution and many other factors play a role, but that goes with both filtered and non-filtered indexes.

Comment: +1, [lots of limitations to be aware of though - this blog post is not even totally exhaustive](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/04/t-sql-queries/filtered-indexes).

Comment: Great point, Aaron.  Thanks for the additional information!

Comment: An example from a co-worker: A table of people, the vast majority, say 99.9%, of which are male. You could place an index on the Gender column with a filter of `Gender <> 'm'`. That way, a query `WHERE Gender = 'm'` would use a table scan, `WHERE Gender = 'f'` would use an index, with no overhead of indexing 99.9% of the rows.